# Changed my Password with Root and now I'm stuck out of my own laptop

Tags: system-installation, login, password

cool nerds of the Internet

I changed my forgotten password with root and it won't work, I'm currently using guest login which is so annoying
so I was thinking I'm being a smart-head when I deleted the password with root but it still won't login!!!
help me to reinstall it or whatever solution you guys might have.

PS : when I change the password with root and it gives me that "type new password" line I try to type and it doesn't do anything, like the keyboard is numb or something, the only thing that works in this stage is "Enter" so I entered two empty lines and it gave me the "password not changed" I don't even know how I changed it the first time.

HELP A SISTER

Comment: The terminal doesn't record passwords for security purposes. When you're prompted for one, it won't show what you type, but it is taking it.

Comment: it still won't login to my account when I deleted the password.